# Version number in jar file name - how to set classpath in manifest file properly?

Tags: java, jar, ear

I have a set of jars which will eventually be deployed as an ear to WebSphere. When each of these jars is built, the manifest file gets a Class-Path entry with all the jars that are dependencies. Later, when the ear is deployed, these entries are used by WebSphere to determine the visibility.

Up to now, we used jar names without versions, but we want to introduce jar names with versions in it (like foo-1.0.0.jar). The problem is the following:

When I build a jar file, I might depend on foo-1.0.0.jar, so that this jar goes into the manifest file. Later, when the ear file is built, foo-1.0.5.jar is included because this is the stable version. Now my manifest file contains a reference to a file that is not included in the ear. What can I do about it? Or did I miss something important?